# Collect all custom posts into one page with page template - Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a custom post type and on one page in custom theme I wont to show few post types and below that read more, when you click on read more all post types should be shown on one page with custom template. I try with single.php but no luck.

This part shows 10 posts on the pages with title as a link

```
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'faq', 'posts_per_page' => 10);
$faq = new WP_Query( $args );

while($faq->have_posts()) {
    // create a new number_row block
    $tpl->newBlock ( "faq-item" );

    $faq->the_post();

    // assign values
    $tpl->assign ( "link",          get_the_permalink() );
    $tpl->assign ( "title",         get_the_title() );
    $tpl->assign ( "text",          get_the_excerpt() );
}
```

and this part on the tpl page shos that 10 post from a controller:

```
<div class=" {category-faq} col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 pad-top-fixed-5 pad-right-percent-0 pad-bottom-fixed-10 pad-left-percent-0 blue-navy-f-1 font-14" >
    <a href="{link}"> {title} </a>
</div>
```

I just need under these 10 to show link read more and to get on the page where is all faq listed

And this is a new page tpl where i need to show all posts.

```
<!-- INCLUDE BLOCK : header -->

<!--  Building unknown container  -->
<div class="row container-fluid pad-left-percent-19 pad-right-percent-19 gray-bg-1" style="min-height: 700px;>

    <!--  Row 1  -->
    <div class=" col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 pad-all-0   ">

<!--  Full width right and left  -->
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-9 pad-all-0">
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div id="border-right-1" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 marg-top-fixed-15 pad-left-percent-0 ">
                <p class="blue-navy-f-2 font-12 gray-f-2"><a href="/residential">Home</a><a href="/help-and-advice/">/Help and Advice</a></p>
                <!-- Color for entire left 9/12 column  -->
                <p class="font-50 font-l-600 font-f-bariol-regular gray-f-4 pad-bottom-percent-1">{title}</p>
                <p class="font-14 gray-f-2 pad-bottom-percent-1">{content}</p>
            </div>
            <!-- End of Registering interest column -->
        </div>
    </div> <!-- End of Color for entire left 9/12 column  -->
</div> <!-- Color for entire left 9/12 column  -->

<div id="get-touch-bu" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-3 marg-top-fixed-15" >
    <div id="get-touch-bu" class="pad-left-fixed-15 pad-top-percent-10"  >
        <!-- INCLUDE BLOCK : twitter -->
    </div>
</div>

</div> <!-- End Full width right and left  -->
</div><!--  Row 1  -->

<!-- End of List container row  -->
```

Comment: Please include your code in the question.

Comment: By coding, what have you  tried? Show your code.

Comment: have you created new page template to display all the custom post?

Comment: @YogeshPawar yap it look like this I'll put it in a question